# Specify Drawer Size - Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer, android-layout-weight

I have a drawer which is working fine on a large device but takes up the whole screen on a smaller device, i have tried using a weight but without success, maybe i am implementing it wrong? Code below. help appreciated, thanks.

Without Weight

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="325dp"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

With weight but still not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="2"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete implementation of NavgiationView layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/cin7toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContentSecure"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu_secure" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Hope that works for you.